# Whats the cmd/powershell equivalent of `which` on bash?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I would like to find out which version of an executable the CMD shell uses. In any unix shell, I would use `which` to find it.

Is there an equivalent command in one of the Windows shells?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Various.

1. `where` is a direct equivalent:

   ```
   C:\Users\Joey>where cmd
   C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
   ```

   Note that in PowerShell `where` itself is an alias for `Where-Object`, thus you need to use `where.exe` in PowerShell.
2. In `cmd` you can also use `for`:

   ```
   C:\Users\Joey>for %x in (powershell.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:x
   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
   ```
3. In PowerShell you have `Get-Command` and its alias `gcm` which does the same if you pass an argument (but also works for aliases, cmdlets and functions in PowerShell):

   ```
   PS C:\Users\Joey> Get-Command where

   CommandType     Name          Definition
   -----------     ----          ----------
   Alias           where         Where-Object
   Application     where.exe     C:\Windows\system32\where.exe
   ```

   The first returned command is the one that would be executed.

Comment: For some reason, `where` didn't work for me at all (printed nothing and immediately quit), but `gcm` worked great.

Comment: @Hassan: As you can glean from the sample output of `Get-Command where` on PowerShell, `where` is actually an alias for `Where-Object`, which takes precedence over `where.exe`. To run `where.exe`, you have to enter `where.exe`. At least in PowerShell.

Comment: Oh. Yeah that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: In CMD, typing `where cmd` works but `where dir` gives me "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)". In bash, for comparison, typing `which ls` will show me the location of the `ls` executable. Does this mean it is not a "direct equivalent"?

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson: `dir` is a built-in command of `cmd` and not an executable that's anywhere in the file system. Which also means, running `dir` will never execute any external command. If you try with something that cannot be provided as an external command in a Unix shell (e.g. `cd`) you will find that it also doesn't exist. Which commands are executables and which ones are shell built-ins varies by platform and shell, of course. And some things like `[` can be both, as far as I remember, and are handled as built-ins in scripts for performance reasons.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation Joey! If I follow you, it sounds like this is more of a difference in the OSs than an difference in the shells. You peaked my curiosity though, since running `which cd` does in fact return `/usr/bin/cd` for me (running Red Hat v8.4, and the shell I'm using is zsh). I wonder if there is another example that could be used, or if basically all commands on Linux are also executables?

Answer (score 5):

The `WHERE` command is not quite the same as unix `which` because it lists all matching files found in the current directory or PATH. As Joey says, the first one listed is the one that what execute. It is simple to create a batch script that will only return the first one found.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('where %1') do (
  echo %%F
  exit /b
)
```

But `WHERE` is relatively slow.

Below is a WHICH.BAT script that is faster and does a bit more. It uses extensive delayed expansion toggling because: 1) Expanding %PATH% is unreliable if there are unquoted special characters. 2) Expanding FOR variables while delayed expansion is enabled corrupts values that contain `!`.

```
::WHICH.BAT  CommandName  [ReturnVar]
::
::  Determines the full path of the file that would execute if
::  CommandName were executed.
::
::  The result is stored in variable ReturnVar, or else it is
::  echoed to stdout if ReturnVar is not specified.
::
::  If no file is found, then an error message is echoed to stderr.
::
::  The ERRORLEVEL is set to one of the following values
::    0 - Success: A matching file was found
::    1 - CommandName is an internal command
::    2 - No file was found and CommandName is not an internal command
::    3 - Improper syntax - no CommandName specified
::
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "file=%~1"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

if not defined file (
  >&2 echo Syntax error: No CommandName specified
  exit /b 3
)


:: test for internal command
echo(!file!|findstr /i "[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]" >nul || (
  set "empty=!temp!\emptyFolder"
  md "!empty!" 2>nul
  del /q "!empty!\*" 2>nul >nul
  setlocal
  pushd "!empty!"
  set path=
  (call )
  !file! /? >nul 2>nul
  if not errorlevel 9009 (
    >&2 echo "!file!" is an internal command
    popd
    exit /b 1
  )
  popd
  endlocal
)


:: test for external command
set "noExt="
if "%~x1" neq "" if "!PATHEXT:%~x1=!" neq "!PATHEXT!" set noExt="";
set "modpath=.\;!PATH!"
@for %%E in (%noExt%%PATHEXT%) do @for %%F in ("!file!%%~E") do (
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  if not "%%~$modpath:F"=="" if not exist "%%~$modpath:F\" (
    endlocal & endlocal & endlocal
    if "%~2"=="" (echo %%~$modpath:F) else set "%~2=%%~$modpath:F"
    exit /b 0
  )
  endlocal
)
endlocal


>&2 echo "%~1" is not a valid command
exit /b 2
```

**UPDATE**

I had to significantly modify the script above because it was incorrectly listing an internal command as external if there happened to exist an exe file with the same root name somewhere in the PATH.